# How can I use google.script.run properly?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I've been recently working on a project that sends values to a google spreadsheet and
the failure handler always gives me an alert, am I doing something wrong?

By the way, here's the code:

**MainGsFile.gs**:

```
var Server = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("Spreadsheet Url"); 
//I know that's not the Spreadsheet Url
var Pages = Server.getSheets();
function doGet() 
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("MainHtmlFile");
}
function SetCellValue(PageNum, Row, Column, Value)
{
  Page[PageNum].getRange(Row, Column).setValue(Value);
}
function GetCellValue(PageNum, Row, Column)
{
  return Page[PageNum].getRange(Row, Column).getValue();
}
```

**MainHtmlFile.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--HTML Code-->
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="Test()">It's going to work</button>
  </body>
</html>
<!--CSS Code-->
<style>
//Styles go here
</style>
<!--JavaScript Code-->
<script>
  function Test()
  {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(OnSuccess).withFailureHandler(OnFailure).SetCellValue(1, 1, 1, "true");
  } 
  function OnSuccess()
  {
    alert("Yes");
  }
  function OnFailure()
  {
    alert("No");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: When I saw your script, `Page` is used at `Page[PageNum].getRange(Row, Column).setValue(Value);`, while `Pages` is used at `var Pages = Server.getSheets();`. I think that this is the reason of your issue. In your script, `Page` is used 2 times. From this situation, how about modifying `var Pages = Server.getSheets();` to `var Page = Server.getSheets();`? But, the 1st index of the value of `Page` is `0`. Please be careful this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Comment: Can you provide more details on the issue? What alert are you seeing? If it is `yes` or  `no` it is due to the success and failure handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

You can't pass mutiples arguments. Trick is to use object :

```
var obj = {};
obj.value = 1;
obj.value2 = 2;
obj.value3 = 3;
obj.bool = true;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(OnSuccess).withFailureHandler(OnFailure).SetCellValue(obj);
```